# Adding constraints programmatically to topLayoutGuide?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

If I constrain a UITableView to its super view in viewDidLoad() of the viewController everything works perfectly.

However, if I attempt to constrain the tableView to the top of the layoutGuide like this:

```
 // tableView.top = view.top
myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintWithItem:theTableView
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
               toItem:self.view
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
               multiplier:1.0
               constant:0];
myConstraint.identifier = @"tableView.top = layoutguide.bottom";
[self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];
```

I get this error:

```
    [UIViewController topLayoutGuide]: guide not available before the view controller's view is loaded
2016-06-03 10:48:06.310 BlinkPDF[304:34590] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs'
```

I tried moving all my constraints into the -(void) updateConstraints method of the viewController and that eliminated the run time error and it rendered the view correctly, however, when I rotated the device the view did not update properly.

Can anyone tell me the correct place to write that constraint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to call your updateConstraints to viewDidAppear and add this line before calling method 

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

So your viewDidAppear method will be like

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];
       [self updateConstraints];
    }
```

This will help you.